# Connection using soap api magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v1

I am unable to connect to generate the sessionid using soap api in **magento1.9.**

I am getting the following error message:

> Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://test.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1' : Premature end of data in tag
>   html line 3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please to add index.php after base url like below

https://test.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1' to https://test.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl=1'